# How do i mimic one org to another org in Salesforce?

Tags: migration, org

I would like to know how can I migrate/mimic one org to another org?

Says I have 1 org (org A) with some custom fields on cases and the page layout was edited and I have another new org (org B) which is all standard, never edit before. Now I want the **org B** to have the same case layout & field from my **org A**.

I tried use Eclipse -Salesforce IDE to migrate and it give me errors something like -> 'Booking value is missing'. In **my org A** I have additional value for Case Status field, 'Booking' is one of it.

When I migrate from **org A** to **org B**, wouldn't it auto insert those new value for me? I have to ensure all value in **org A** is present in **org B** then only I can migrate from **org A** to **org B**?

Or is there other best practice to do org migration?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to migrate the data model or the actual data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're heading along the right lines, but you need to select all of the objects/fields etc. from the metadata lists that you want to migrate. It won't automatically fulfil any dependancies so you're going to need to include the Case object as part of your deployment.